# One or more errors occurred. (Permission denied /var/run/iotedge/mgmt.sock) caused by: docker returned exit code:

Tags: linux, docker, raspberry-pi, iot, azure-iot-edge

I just installed IoTEdge on Raspberry strech following this:[Azure/InternetofThings/IoTEdge/Install or uninstall the Azure IoT Edge runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge?view=iotedge-2018-06&tabs=linux)

However I get these errors below.

3 weeks I installed another one and it worked perfectly with the same instructions.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/iotedge $ sudo iotedge check --verbose
Configuration checks
--------------------
√ config.yaml is well-formed - OK
√ config.yaml has well-formed connection string - OK
√ container engine is installed and functional - OK
√ config.yaml has correct hostname - OK
× config.yaml has correct URIs for daemon mgmt endpoint - Error
    One or more errors occurred. (Permission denied /var/run/iotedge/mgmt.sock)
        caused by: docker returned exit code: 1, stderr = One or more errors occurred. (Permission denied /var/run/iotedge/mgmt.sock)
√ latest security daemon - OK
√ host time is close to real time - OK
√ container time is close to host time - OK
‼ DNS server - Warning
    Container engine is not configured with DNS server setting, which may impact connectivity to IoT Hub.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-dns for best practices.
    You can ignore this warning if you are setting DNS server per module in the Edge deployment.
        caused by: Could not open container engine config file /etc/docker/daemon.json
        caused by: No such file or directory (os error 2)
‼ production readiness: certificates - Warning
    The Edge device is using self-signed automatically-generated development certificates.
    They will expire in 89 days (at 2021-02-22 07:24:52 UTC) causing module-to-module and downstream device communication to fail on an active deployment.
    After the certs have expired, restarting the IoT Edge daemon will trigger it to generate new development certs.
    Please consider using production certificates instead. See https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-certs for best practices.
√ production readiness: container engine - OK
‼ production readiness: logs policy - Warning
    Container engine is not configured to rotate module logs which may cause it run out of disk space.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-logs for best practices.
    You can ignore this warning if you are setting log policy per module in the Edge deployment.
        caused by: Could not open container engine config file /etc/docker/daemon.json
        caused by: No such file or directory (os error 2)
‼ production readiness: Edge Agent's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Warning
    The edgeAgent module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeAgent directory on the host filesystem.
    Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.
× production readiness: Edge Hub's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Error
    Could not check current state of edgeHub container
        caused by: docker returned exit code: 1, stderr = Error: No such object: edgeHub

Connectivity checks
-------------------
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with IoT Hub AMQP port - OK
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with IoT Hub HTTPS / WebSockets port - OK
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with IoT Hub MQTT port - OK
√ container on the default network can connect to IoT Hub AMQP port - OK
√ container on the default network can connect to IoT Hub HTTPS / WebSockets port - OK
√ container on the default network can connect to IoT Hub MQTT port - OK
√ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to IoT Hub AMQP port - OK
√ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to IoT Hub HTTPS / WebSockets port - OK
√ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to IoT Hub MQTT port - OK

17 check(s) succeeded.
4 check(s) raised warnings.
2 check(s) raised errors.
```

iotedge list

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iotedge list
A module runtime error occurred
        caused by: Could not list modules
        caused by: connection error: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)
```

Comment: Hi Luis, could you update your question with the version of the OS and the version of the Azure IoT Edge runtime? Azure IoT Edge was updated a few days ago.

Comment: i s there a command to get these versions?

Comment: nevermind: its raspberry strech with
iotedge 1.0.10.2

Comment: what is the output of command ```iotedge list```?

Comment: I have updated the question with the output of iotedgelist

Comment: Try `systemctl restart docker` and then restart your iotedge service.

Comment: thhanks, but that doesnt fix the issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Is no one here that can help with this?

Comment: Same issue here.